# Oblique projection for which the projection vector is at an angle of 45 degrees

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, projection

dixit:

*A special case of oblique projection is called cavalier projection. It is given when the projection vector forms an angle of 45° with the z-axis. This means that:
$$(x_p^2+y_p^2)/z_p^2=1$$*

My question is: where does this equation comes from??

Answer (score 0):

The two legs of a $45^\circ$ triangle are equal.  The two legs of the triangle in question are $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $z$.  You can take it from there.

Comment: i cant grasp the idea, can you give a example? I only know the degree of the angle that the projection vector forms with the z-axis